# Grails 3 root directory

Tags: grails

I use `ServletContextHolder.getServletContext().getRealPath("")` to create a directory and transfer some file there. How could I find the directory and check whether the transfer successful or not

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Per [ServletContext API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29) getRealPath actual gives the real path to a file - say getRealPath("index.html") would give you the real path to the file index.html.  It won't create the directory.

Comment: I didn't describe clearly. I mean I find the root directory and make a new sub directory under the root directory and transfer a file to the sub directory. How i can check whether the file is there or not? Thanks

Comment: I generally define the directory I'm going to write the files to - either by an environment variable or a variable defined in Config.groovy.  There are other ways to do it - but that way you have an easy handle to the directory from wherever you need it.